# Merge data from one table to an other with removing duplicates - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to copy from a table to an other with "filtering the data": I want to remove duplicates based on a column (date of statistic) but the following script copies all the rows. What am I missing, or how should it be properly handled? I am also open for a solution that does not not copy to a new table but does it in the correct one.

```
MERGE INTO TEMP temp
  USING ORIG orig
    ON (temp.DATE_OF_STATISTIC = orig.DATE_OF_STATISTIC)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET temp.COUNT = temp.COUNT + orig.COUNT
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID, DATE_OF_STATISTIC, COUNT)
    VALUES (orig.ID, orig.DATE_OF_STATISTIC, orig.COUNT);
```

DATE_OF_STATISTIC is a VARCHAR2 column with format: dd-mm-yyyy for example: 20-12-2014

In case of duplicate i have to select one of the records (doesnt matter which one) and merge the count values in it.

Comment: Is date_of_statistic a DATE type? if so, do you need to TRUNC these values first to ensure the fractional date is not causing an issue?

Comment: Can you give an example for "duplicate rows"? If there are more than one row with the same date_of_statistics but different count, which one should be taken?

Comment: it is a varchar with format dd--mm-yyyy: for example 20-12-2014 to avoid fractional date issue, it doesnt matter which record we delete but the count value must be merged

Comment: To avoid? Really? You didn't avoid any issue, rather you have created an issue with improper data type. To get rid of time part, `trunc` would do the job.

Comment: Botg of them is varchar2

Comment: A sample data is required.

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the issue at small scale? If so, maybe you should provide a [minimum but complete example containing few problematic rows](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we could all try to find a solution?

Comment: You do not need MERGE here. You need update + delete or INSERT into TEMP. MERGE doesn't give you anything here

Answer (score 3):

> What am I missing [..] ?

The one thing you missed is `MERGE` will check for matching rows *before* actually performing the merge operation. So it will not take into account any row added during processing. That's why you might end up having duplicate records when `orig` has two rows with the same date.

Your only solution here is to merge on an aggregate sub-query as it has already been suggested in other answers:

```
MERGE INTO TEMP2 temp
  USING (SELECT MIN(id) "ID", SUM("COUNT") "COUNT", DATE_OF_STATISTIC
         FROM ORIG GROUP BY DATE_OF_STATISTIC) orig
    --             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    --          aggregates rows by DATE_OF_STATISTIC

    ON (temp.DATE_OF_STATISTIC = orig.DATE_OF_STATISTIC)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET temp."COUNT" = temp."COUNT" + orig."COUNT"
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID, DATE_OF_STATISTIC, COUNT)
    VALUES (orig.ID, orig.DATE_OF_STATISTIC, orig."COUNT");
```

---

If `temp` table is *empty* before processing, this could further be reduced to a simple `CREATE ... SELECT` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE temp3 AS (SELECT  MIN(id) "ID", SUM("COUNT") "COUNT", DATE_OF_STATISTIC
         FROM ORIG GROUP BY DATE_OF_STATISTIC);
```

Or if you really need two different statements, as a `CREATE TABLE` followed by an `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE temp4 .... ;
--                 ^^^^^
--            whatever you need here    

INSERT INTO temp4 SELECT MIN(id) "ID", SUM("COUNT") "COUNT", DATE_OF_STATISTIC
         FROM ORIG GROUP BY DATE_OF_STATISTIC;
```

---

Compare all those solutions on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a42f/1

Comment: Yeah thats cool, As I can see i dont even need merge with this select and an insert i cna solve the issue, thanks!

Comment: @enricko As this might help you, I've updated my answer (and the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a42f/1)) to provide examples of `CREATE ... SELECT`  and `INSERT ... SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help. In case of rows with the same date_of_statistic value it will take the row with the hightest id:

```
MERGE INTO TEMP temp
  USING ( SELECT id,
                 date_of_statistic,
                 count
            FROM(SELECT id, 
                        date_of_statistic, 
                        SUM(count) OVER (PARTITION BY date_of_statistic) count,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_of_statistic ORDER BY id DESC) rank
                   FROM ORIG
                )
           WHERE rank = 1        
        ) orig
    ON (temp.DATE_OF_STATISTIC = orig.DATE_OF_STATISTIC)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET temp.COUNT = temp.COUNT + orig.COUNT
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID, DATE_OF_STATISTIC, COUNT)
    VALUES (orig.ID, orig.DATE_OF_STATISTIC, orig.COUNT);
```

Comment: Better however the count value is not merged

Comment: Can you go a little bit more into details? Raises the query an error? Are there no matching rows? Something like that...

Comment: The scrip is running however for example i have this two rows with count = 5 and count 4 and date_of_stat = 12-12-2014 for both the result in the temp table wont be 9 for count it is 5

Comment: So you need the sum of the count of duplicate rows?

Comment: yeah thats what I tried to achive with this part : UPDATE SET temp.OUNT = temp.COUNT + orig.COUNT

Comment: But if you have duplicate rows in the original table you need to sum the count instead of choosing one row randomly, like you told in your question. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

In your `using` clause, instead of just `table name`, select only `unique` rows from the table.

Another thing, do you just want to get rid of `duplicate rows` in `source table`? If yes, then no need of temp table and merge. Just `delete` the duplicates in the source table.

Do you need a query to remove duplicates? If yes, look for `analytic` functions. Based on the rule to pick duplicates, I can suggest further. Mention on what basis the rows are duplicate. Some sample data would be much better.

Comment: Not just remove, i have to merge the values in COUNT column, it doesntt matter which records is deleted

Comment: I can't find a reference to the `UNIQUE` clause for `MERGE` in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm). Could you elaborate  a little or give a pointer to the right doc?

Comment: I didn't say `unique` clause, did I? I said, `using` clause. `using(select col_list,analytic func...from table) alias` to pick only unique rows based on OP's rule for duplicate. Makes sense?

Comment: Ah ok: as it was formatted as <code> I though it was a SQL clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into TEMP
select ID, DATE_OF_STATISTIC, s from (
    select orig.ID, orig.DATE_OF_STATISTIC, 
           sum(orig.COUNT) over(partition by orig.DATE_OF_STATISTIC) s,
           row_number() over(partition by orig.DATE_OF_STATISTIC order by orig.id desc) rw
    from ORIG orig)
where rw = 1;
```